# Start or Stop a jetty ServerConnector without server restart

Tags: java, server, jetty, embedded-jetty

I use jetty server to handle client requests and have a requirement where I need to start or stop one or few ServerConnectors on demand without restarting the server to which these connectors are attached to.

For example.

```
ServerConnector httpConnector;
ServerConnector httpsConnector;
Server server;
server.addConnector(httpConnector);
server.addConnector(httpsConnector);
server.start()
```

Need to start/stop/cancel a particular connector without forcing server to restart.

Comment: Why?  If its to update security certificates (TLS/SSL), know that the ServerConnector does not need to be restarted for that.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Why not? ;-) If you temporarily disable access to the server on a particular port (but still keep it running on the others), stopping the connector sounds like a reasonable way.

Comment: Connectors are only for accepting connections, existing connections are not impacted.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Question is about stopping and starting a connector, not aborting currently active connections.

Comment: regarding serverconnector.close(). "Once a connector has been closed, it cannot be opened again without first calling LifeCycle.stop() and it will not be active again until a subsequent call to LifeCycle.start()"

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt its not for certificate updates. I have customers who want unsecured port to be enabled/disabled without effecting traffic on other ports bound to that server

Comment: `ServerConnector.close()` stops the associated `java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel` and unbinds to the local port (local port will be `-2` once you do this).  Those JVM classes are only created during `.start()`, so a stop/start cycle is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to do the following ...

```java
// TODO: Have a reference to the Connector you are going to work with

// Remove from server first.
server.removeConnector(connector);

// Stop the connector.
// NOTE: Existing connections will still live on.  
// This will only stop accepting new connections.
connector.stop(); // might take a while (waiting for acceptors to close)

// TODO: do what you want with this connector

// Eg: harshly close existing connections
connector.getConnectedEndPoints().forEach((endpoint)-> {
    endpoint.close();
});

// Re-add stopped connector if you want
// This will start connector as well
// This can fail (eg: if port is already in use)
server.addConnector(connector);
```

Comment: And then start the connector if required, I had to start it explicitly (connector.start()). Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm: the connector needs to be started again via connector.start() for this to work. It won't accept connections otherwise after being added.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `stop` on the connector to stop it and `start` to start it again. To get the relevant connector there are two solutions:

- Keep the created connector-instances somewhere and call the methods
- Get all connectors of a server by calling `getConnectors`, iterate over them, find the one you want to stop and call `stop` or `start` on it to stop or start it.

Comment: Have to remove it from the server too.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Why? I just tried it here. After stopping the connector I get errors in the browser when trying to access that port and get answers again (from a servlet) after starting the connector again.

Comment: The connector is still there, with references and holds to various resources (OS based and Java based, acceptor thread allocations, reserved thread calculations, connector statistics handling, error handling, redirect handling, etc).  On some versions of windows (for example) you cannot restart it that way.  It has to be removed from the Bean and LifeCycle hierarchy first.